# Open source code snippet repository

Tags: c#, open-source, code-snippets

Does anyone know of a good and simple open source code snippet repository? Ive seen many that are free services, but I want to host it myself. A few google searches just find the free services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean?  Do you want one for your own personal use (what is wrong with the [built in snippet management](http://devshaped.com/2009/01/accelerate-your-coding-with-code-snippets/) in visual studio?  Are you looking for examples of design patterns?  In that case maybe check [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/CatalogCSharp.htm) or the [portland pattern repository](http://c2.com/ppr/).  For snippets such as looping constructs, try catches, etc i love Coderush templates.

That being said, my personal opinion is that snippets are as evil as copy-paste.  What you probably want is to refactor so that there is no duplicate code.  And if you need to share code between projects - some sort of core library might be the way to go.

**Edit:** In the comments below you specify that you want snippets available via web.  I don't have anything to recommend thats exactly like that but you should look into storing your snippets in visual studio and syncing them using LiveMesh.  I know of several people that do something similar and they like it.

OOoooor...what's wrong with just a wordpress blog?  You can set it to private access only.  You get tagging, searching, syntax highlighting (via the google syntax highlight plugin) and a nearly 0  fuss setup.

Comment: I want a library of code snippets that I can access from any computer connected to the internet, but hosted and controlled by myself.

Comment: See my edit, a couple of good possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) with [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) plug-in for that. Selfhosted, easy, and all done by couple clicks :)

Comment: I was thinking about that, but can you lock down certain posts to be private to only certain authenticated users?

Comment: @RyanOC: Yes you can. Have a WordPress blog myself, and I've done it :)

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) not good enough? Also, there is [GitHub](http://github.com/) if you preffer `git` to `svn`.

Granted, it's not for short snippets, mainly, but you could easely use it for that.

---

### Edit

Reading again your question and your comments, what you really want is an existing, open source, system to hold short pieces of text made in c#?

I'd guess you'd have to do that yourself, I know of no project to do *just* that :S

Comment: Im looking for a web application that I host that will hold my snippets.

Comment: Why can't you use a standard repository for that? With http://code.google.com/ you can make 1 file per snippet, and access them through a browser. The only *difficulty* could be the upload, but *if you are a developer*, most likely, you have a CVS client installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to understand what you mean.

As the top commenter said, there's visual studio. Or there's [Github](http://github.com) but that's for more of version control and can have some annoying sides when trying to organise things.

There's also [Snippet Repo](http://snippetrepo.com) which you can post snippets, favourite other people's stuff. I guess it's like a social code repository.

Answer (score 0):

- [Krugle](http://www.krugle.org) has an excellent base and allows for quick searching and filtering.
- [Active State](http://www.activestate.com) has a some good snippets with excellent reasoning and documentation.

Take a look into [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) in conjunction with a SVN setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still suggest using existing sites. I often use [Google Codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch) when I'm looking for existing examples of how to use a function or boilerplate code (just watch licenses of the code you are borrowing from...)

But it sounds like you're looking to host a pastebin.

pastebin.com has [source code](http://pastebin.com/pastebin.tar.gz) available.

Other variations are available, and wikipedia has a good [comparison of pastebin software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_pastebins).

Comment: Thats very close. My ideal solution would be written in asp.net so I could modify it.I might just have to build one myself.

Answer (score 0):

git + gitosis + gitweb

I have a repository specifically for small one-off scripts I'm unlikely to change or expand.  Doing something similar for a personal library doesn't seem unreasonable.  You want to manage source code; that's what source control is for.